# How to change System Navigation Bar (default) icon color?

Tags: android, navigation, uinavigationbar, system, default

I want to change the color of the system navigation bar icon color but could only succeed to change the navigation bar background color, using these codes programmatically:

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/black</item>



if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            window.navigationBarColor = resources.getColor(R.color.primary_text_color)
            window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION //For setting material color into black of the navigation bar
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK, you can have only light or dark navigation icon colors

Comment: @Zain share some link Thanks

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/WindowInsetsControllerCompat#setAppearanceLightNavigationBars(boolean) 
`WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView).isAppearanceLightNavigationBars = true|false`

Comment: setAppearanceLightNavigationBars >> This method has no effect on API <26